# Removal of "phrasing" and "there-is" tags

Tags: discussion, retagging

There are only a few dozen questions with these two tags. In the case of "phrasing", I believe it can be replaced with "phrases" in most cases. Should it be made a synonym?

"There-is" can be replaced with "grammatical-number". I'd like to know if there are any objections to this cleaning. Are the amount of "there-is" (versus "there-are"?) questions sufficient to warrant its own tag?

Also, I think this is the 1,001 question (not counting deleted questions). Yay for palindromes!

Comment: 1001 is a palindrome; 1,001 isn't

Comment: @jwpat7 You are technically correct. . . which is the best kind of correct. I also probably should have said "1,001st question".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’d prefer that the “there is/are” questions keep a dedicated tag, because this covers things beyond number.

I don’t necessarily see that “phrases” and “phrasing” are the same, because “phrases” sounds like phrase requests. Well, ok: so does the other one. Hm.

Comment: Good point on the "phrase-requests". I think in that case most "phrasing" questions fall into either tag: requesting a phrase or understanding how something is phrased.